# Discrepancy in flag number in chat

Tags: bug, chat, flags

[image: picture of a icon with a flag in chat with no flags]

Well, which is it? One flag or no flags? I do have the `all` tab selected, so that's not the problem. The flag circle in chat itself is unaffected, only the flags tab and the top bar of chat.SE/MSO/SO appear to show this issue. It also doesn't go away on-click.

Comment: sound like a cache bug... I'll take a peek

Comment: It looks like this was simply a cached/denormalized value gone awry - it is now resolved (it fixed itself).

Comment: @marc Just FYI, it seems to be happening again.

Comment: Bumping because I'm seeing this right now.

Comment: It's still happening and I hate it and make it go away

Comment: The devs brought the bug back by "popular demand"!

Comment: I'm also seeing it.

Comment: I've had this a couple times now.

Comment: @marc this still happens. There is a `1` up there half the time, when there really aren't any flags.