# Wrong flag count in chat.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Discrepancy in flag number in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79464/discrepancy-in-flag-number-in-chat)

Following image explains it all:

[image]

Am I the only one seeing this? Is it a bug? Link for this: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/admin/flagged?show=all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That flag count is heavily cached, it often stays around for hours after the flags were dismissed. The caching is certainly intentional and not a bug, although there might be some bugs causing it to be cached for longer than intended.

Comment: This pretty much sums it up, although in most cases, this should not happen. There are some edge conditions (race conditions, really) that can cause that number to be off; there's a scheduled job that cleans this up (it's fixed now).

Comment: I think SE caches quite much data.(may be most of the counts)