# Why did I get a notification for spam/offensive flags in chat?

Tags: support, chat, chat-flags

[image]

This is confusing because:

1. It's the first time I got such a notification
2. But there's nothing there
3. On refresh the blue `[1]` stays there - On Chrome, where caching is chaotic, could it be stale cache?
4. And finally, why would I see spam/offensive flags in chat at all?

Notification went away after a few refreshes, but now it's back, and refuses to go away (after at least 5 refreshes)...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You see spam/offensive chat flags because you have 10k rep network wide:

[image]

You can mark flags valid or invalid, and if they get 6 more valid votes than invalid the post is automatically deleted and the user suspended temporarily. Moderators on all Stack Exchange sites can see the flags as well, and if they vote the flag is dismissed immediately, so flags tend not to last long. Unfortunately, the chat system has a habit of showing the flag indicator long after a flag has been dismissed; it's possibly a [caching problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79464/discrepancy-in-flag-number-in-chat)

Comment: Is there a privileges help page for chat that I somehow missed? I know chat is still a work in progress, just wondering if I missed it. I dismissed the possibility of seeing flags because my net rep is 10K, because I felt it would be kind of strange that I got access to a feature that's normally considered a 10K privilege, without passing the 10K mark in any of the sites I'm participating... But since chat is network wide, it makes some sense, I guess.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox Some are mentioned on the [main site privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges), and some are in the [FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq). I think the best list is in [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87761/is-there-a-list-of-se-chat-privileges-and-the-minimum-reputation-required-for-t)

Comment: Thanks, the 10k rep chat privileges seem pretty basic, so it makes much more sense now...