# Where can I find explanations about flags?

Tags: support, flags

I know this is a newbie  question, and most likely a duplicate, but for some reason can find it. Were do I find the explanations about flags, what they are in one compact place. I resonantly flagged a comment as offensive, but it was declined. Latter I discovered that the definition of offensive is something other than I thought. Although the comment was clearly offensive towards me it was not offensive in the definition of the flag so I was incorrect to flag it as such. So yes, to avoid it in the future:

Where can I find the definition and usage of all the flags?

Comment: In your case, see: [What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: @JoshC yes that was exactly the question were I learned why I was wrong to flag it, it does explain about two of the flags in detail, but not all of them.

Comment: @Random, hopefully this works. Were is the duplicate question? I would not ask if I could find it!

Comment: Are you asking only of comment flags specifically and not offensive flags as an interpretive whole?

Comment: @random no it's a general question about all of the flags, on comments/questions/third place I am  not aware off, if there are differences between question & comment flags etc. Basically a complete beginners guide to flags nothing spared.

Comment: It would not be in one place because no one would read it, instead, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118897/why-did-i-get-a-notification-for-spam-offensive-flags-in-chat http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work